# write to JSON Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to find a good tutorial that would guide me to write to a JSON file. and also to read from a JSON file and populate `core-data` with it.

I have `googled` for days, and couldn't find a good tutorial. Can someone give me a sample code or point me to a good tutorial. I am new to objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to introduce the structure of JSON, http://json.org/
and if you scroll down, you will find links to several open-source (which you can use as examples) projects which implement JSON serializing and deserializing. basically, there, you will find much more code examples in their projects than anyone here can ever really post as a response to your question.